# How to stop "setVertexArrayObject: set vao to" message in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting lots of messages in the console. Following is the sample of the log.

setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 4 5

Due to this logs, I am not able to debug properly my app as it keep scrolling every time. How can I stop these messages?

Comment: is this happening in android only?

Comment: Yes, this is on Android only

Comment: Android's logs are very busy. Ignore most of what it has to say.

Comment: @TedHenry yes but they are hundreds of in one seconds... I cannot see my messages...

Comment: Perhaps run your app from Android Studio so you can filter the log? I don't know if you can filter the log in VSCode.

Comment: try flutter clean

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP. I don't know if it's related but my hot reload on stopped working at the same time I started getting those messages.

Comment: In VSCode debug console type !setVertex to filter it out until a fix arrives.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

if you're on Dev or Beta channel, downgrade your flutter to a Stable version would probably solve your problem.

The easiest way to do so is by running the command `flutter version` 
(different from the checking version command `flutter  --version`).

find current versions here:
[Flutter SDK releases](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos)

Comment: You are right.. changing it to stable version stopped it. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Even though I am on the latest stable channel, I still see this filling up the console log.
`Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 0b8abb4724 (4 days ago) • 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
Engine • revision e1e6ced81d
Tools • Dart 2.7.0`

Comment: I was already on a stable channel and keep getting these messages.

Comment: I get this message with flutter version 1.17.4 and emulator not real devices

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be [related to certain Android Emulators or Google packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299236/eglcodeccommon-setvertexarrayobject-set-vao-debug-message)
For me these messages stopped logging when I refactored my code and removed the WebView package. If removing a package or debugging on an iPhone simulator or real device is not possible for you, then you can filter these message out. In VS Code you can filter to see only Flutter output in the debug console by filtering on `I/flutter`

[image]