# eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao debug message

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have Android Emulator (API 28) logcat fludded by messages like this.

```
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 29 30
```

What is that and should I worry about it?

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior today... you ever figure this out?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

It finally stopped using the Android 11 emulator.

Comment: Well, now the message just replaced TAG to "EGL_emulation". :/

Answer (score 4):

I just commented out mAdView.loadAd(adRequest) in my MainActivity and I stopped seeing this message.

You can turn this off just in debug mode by doing something like this:

```
if(bannerAd != null && !kDebugMode) bannerAd!.load()
```

Comment: This solved the problem on my device. No logcat flooding anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but no more ads -- it this really the fix?

Comment: I think what he means to say it: They come from Google Ads :)

Comment: I have the same problem with no ads in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the Google Ad. If you are using Google Ads then you can see these type of logs.

Answer (score 0):

this log is about a view or somethings related to UI that has been creating continuously, for example it can be a simple progress view which is progressing and you forget to gone it.

and it's common when you use some views overlapping each other while one of them are visible at a time and the other one is invisible, try to set the visibility of the hidden view to 'Gone' instead of 'invisible'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an animated gif image displayed inside WebView. After image removal setVertexArrayObject flooding message disappeared.

Comment: This one is interesting...